# Sublime > Select between jsx tags

Tags: reactjs, sublimetext3, jsx

Just wondering if anyone knew how to select between jsx tags in sublime. Being able to do so would be super useful!

Here is an example of the jsx I'd like to select:

```
<div>
  <SelectBetweenMe>
    <AnotherTag>

    </AnotherTag>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </SelectBetweenMe>

</div>
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you indent your code correctly, you can use `ctrl(cmd) + shift + J` to select all the content which in the same indentation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just started using JS prettier so this will actually work now. Thanks!